# How can I convert ListView to GridView?

Tags: android, list, gridview, android-listview

I have created an applicaton that shows a `listview` of some pictures from the internet in ListView. I want to show it in a `GridView`.I have tried using base adapter in place of list adapter! But that doesn't work as it cant take arg (the arg is  in the code)

Can anyone help me to show this images in `gridview`?

Here is my code.

MainPage.java

```
public class MainPage extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("");

        setContentView(R.   layout.    contacts_list);

        final List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();

        /** This block is for getting the <span id="IL_AD9" class="IL_AD">image url</span> to <span id="IL_AD2" class="IL_AD">download from</span> the server **/
        final GetDataFromDB getvalues = new GetDataFromDB();

        final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainPage.this,
                "", "Gettting values from DB", true);
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        new    Thread   (new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String response = getvalues.getImageURLAndDesciptionFromDB();
                System.out.println("Response : " + response);

                dismissDialog(dialog);
                if (!response.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    if (!response.equalsIgnoreCase("error")) {
                        dismissDialog(dialog);

                        // Got the response, now split it to get the image Urls and description
                        String all[] = response.split("##"); 
                        for(int k = 0; k < all.length; k++){
                            String urls_and_desc[] = all[k].split(","); //  urls_and_desc[0] contains image url and [1] -> description.
                            list.add(get(urls_and_desc[1],urls_and_desc[0]));
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    dismissDialog(dialog);
                }
                latch.countDown();
            }
        }).start();
        /*************************** GOT data from Server ********************************************/
 try {
    latch.await();
} catch (InterruptedException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
        ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter = new MyCustomArrayAdapter(this, list);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override 
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
            { 
                 Intent intent = new Intent(MainPage.this, ViewImage.class);
                     Model model = list.get(position);
                     String myURL = model.getURL();

                     intent.putExtra("image", myURL);

                    startActivity(intent);}
        });
                }


    public void dismissDialog(final ProgressDialog dialog){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
    private Model get(String s, String url) {
        return new Model(s, url);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                this);

            // set title
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Exit!");

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to leave?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, close
                        // current activity
                        MainPage.this.finish();
                    }
                  })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
    }
        // your code.

}
```

MyCustomArrayAdapter.java

```
public class MyCustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final List<Model> list;

    public MyCustomArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_layout_relative, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView text;
        protected ImageView image;
        protected ProgressBar pb;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_layout_relative, null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
            viewHolder.text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            viewHolder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            viewHolder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewHolder.pb = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        holder.image.setTag(list.get(position).getURL());
        holder.image.setId(position);
        PbAndImage pb_and_image = new PbAndImage();
        pb_and_image.setImg(holder.image);
        pb_and_image.setPb(holder.pb);
        new DownloadImageTask().execute(pb_and_image);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Model.java

```
public class Model {

    private String name;
    private String url;

    public Model(String name, String url) {
        this.name = name;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getURL() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setURL(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

i wanna ask something else too.kinda off topic.. i am downlaoding images from the urls and display in gridview. but it downloads huge images that takes lots of data. is there anyway i can download thumbnails to that images to reduce data usage?

Comment: You should used `GridView` instead of `ListView`.

Comment: I tried but the custom listadapter does not work with the gridview in xml file

Comment: i can't get it, why you voters gave him voteDown can you comment with explaining why plz? he asked so simply way, but he just gave us a lot info with a lot code so that's why? he gave us a lot coz he don't know where his bad

Comment: Lol nothing like that! Im new here. but the solution he gave that solved my problem! thats why i though i should appreciate him ! thats all. i still have one problem remaining! can u see on his answer's post? please see if u can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

same code but instead of extend listActivity extend normal activity and defining xml with GridView with id foo or what ever you want.

```
GridView foo = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.foo);
ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter = new MyCustomArrayAdapter(this, list);
foo.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: It says the method setListAdapter is undefined for the type GridView

Comment: oh sorry my bad it instead of setListAdapter "setAdapter" and anyway u welcome hehe

Comment: i wanna ask something else too.kinda off topic.. i am downlaoding images from the urls and display in gridview. but it downloads huge images that takes lots of data. is there anyway i can download thumbnails to that umages to reduce data usage?

Comment: you doing a lot work seems it's bigger than you but i think it's good way to learn quickly and this is question not comment right! but here is my answer download small images version from what ever you downloading them if you downloading them from your server create small version images in your server then get them you android app

Comment: i am downloading them from an external server not mine! and those urls will be used to download high quality images in next activity so i cant give the link to smaller images! any other option ?

Comment: i'm sorry i can't answer here coz this place for comments

Comment: i have posted the question in the post. please see